# How to refresh recycler view inside a fragment without having to change tabs

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have a tablayout and viewpgaer in which there are 10 fragments, each fragment sends request to an api and the results are shown in a recycler view in each fragment. A user can make a post and add to our server, after successfully adding a post he is brought back to the respective category in which he has posted. Now, we need to refresh the fragment to update the recycler view to show the new entry. A broadcast is sent to the fragment upon successful post by a user, so the following code is executed:

```
BroadcastReceiver broadRefresh = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        System.out.println("recd broadcast mainact" + intent.getStringExtra("refresh"));
        if (intent.getStringExtra("refresh") != null) {

            getFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .detach(CarsFragment.this)
                    .attach(CarsFragment.this)
                    .commit();
        }
    }
};
```

The fragment oncreateview and onviewcreated gets called again but the recycler view is not updated. I tried clearing the AdsList arraylist and calling the method again for fetching data loadnormalRv(), in that case the page becomes blank and if I change the tab and then come back to this tab, then recycler view with data shows, or if i press some button like fitler or sort on this page then the data shows.

Here is the complete fragment code [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B80WwXxkG7BkRkRqeERrdGhwVWc).
Please help. Thanks.

Comment: if you only need to refresh your recyclerView you can call `notifyDataSetChanged()` (after passing the new dataset to your adapter) . I don't see why you need to detach and attach the same fragment

Comment: @AhmedAbidi the arraylist already has items, when i refetch the data, the .add method adds items at the end , while i need to show the items in chronological order, latest first and so on, the api is sending the items in correct order, but in the arraylist the item gets added at the end, hence i was trying that if fragment gets created again then the arraylist is reinitialized and it would update correctly,tried clearing the arraylist also

Comment: just replace the entire array from the adapter and use notifyDataSetChanged() after that as @AhmedAbidi said

Answer (score 1):

if you want your items from last to first you can add :

```
mLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
mLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
```

to refresh your recycler view you have two options :

- `notifyDataSetChanged()` which will 'redraw' the whole recycler view ( it will restart all animations for all items )
- You can call    `yourAdapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(int positionStart, int itemCount)`
- You can also call `notifyItemChanged(int position)` to refresh just the item at a particular position. That way you will be making an efficient refresh.